# CSS module hover styles when inside another module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

In a React/Webpack app with [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) I have a module `.card` in its own .scss file and another module named `.stat` which is a content to be shown in the `.card`.

What I need to achieve the following, but int the 'css-modules' way:

```
.card:hover .stat {
    color: #000;
}
```

If I @import `.card` inside the `.stat` module, all of the `.card` css is dumped into the `.stat` output, but I only want to be able to use the correct class name for the `.card`.

What's the correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: Are there any better solutions for this problem since it was asked almost 2 years ago?

Answer (score 8):

We had a similar issue in our use of CSS modules. I open an issue https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/102 and it was suggested to me that I should do either one of the following:

1. Clone the component and add a new className attribute to it and compose the new class with the old class:

   ```
   // Card.js
   React.cloneElement(component, {
     className: styles.card, 
   });

   // styles.cssmodule 
   .card {
     composes: card from "...card.cssmodule"; 
   }
   ```
2. Wrap the component in another element and add the classname to this:

   ```
   <div className={styles.card}><MyComponent /></div>
   ```

I didn't like either of these approaches and I'd like to use the strength of css-modules which is the modules part. So we have a fork of the [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/pull/212) which allows you to use `:ref()` to reference imported classes:

```
:import('...card.cssmodule`){
  importedCard: card;
}

:ref(.importedCard):hover .stat {...}
```

Comment: Still looks like this is a workaround, not a true solution (which in turn seems to be non-existent as of now)

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround [React toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com) guys use an approach to add a `data-react-toolbox="component-name"` or `data-role="somerole"` attribute to every component and target the attribute instead of classes where necessary for such situations.